# Minimum mass to make a string taut

Tags: forces, mass

What can we assume that the minimum mass of the body that is hung on a string for it to be taut ? (Is it safe to assume that mass to be the mass of the string itself?)

Comment: What does “taut” mean? If you mean “straight”, a string with mass is never going to be perfectly straight under gravity unless it is hanging straight down.

Comment: Taut doesn't mean anything in physics. You must define the desired tension in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking pertains to a situation as follows:

[image: fig1]

and you are wondering what mass $M$ is needed to have tension in the rope.

The answer is $M>0$, since the pulley is transferring the weight of the mass to tension on the rope.

If you are asking which $M$ is needed to have no sag on the rope (it becomes absolutely straight), then the answer is none, because if the rope has mass $m$ is will *always* sag a bit regardless of the tension.